# Paragraph will not fit it's width

Tags: c#, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I've added dataset field(string) into my report. but it does not format inner text to fit it's width. Text box width is the same as the horizontal line below. Also there are no line breaks in the saved text on database. Please refer the images below.

[Report Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj19b.png)
[Notes Input Textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3AEf.png)

Comment: Have you had a look at the text padding?

Comment: My guess is that there ARE line breaks that aren't showing up in second the Notes pic. I would try a `REPLACE(REPLACE(Fields!NOTES.Value, CHR(13), ""), CHR(10), "")` to see if it changes.

Comment: What formatting options are you using with the field?  Are you using the justify format option for the font?  It would also help to know what version of crystal reports you used to develop the report.  Sometimes formatting issues are due to the crystal engine version.  For example, I use Crystal Reports 2016 to design reports that are used in a 3rd party software system that uses Crystal Engine 11.  There are a lot of formatting options available in CR 2016 that will work fine in development, but the fail to work when published due to Crystal Engine 11 not supporting those features.